# Preventing Man-in-the-middle attacks on non-HTTPS

Tags: security, http, https, man-in-the-middle

Is there any way to prevent or detect a man-in-the-middle attack over plain HTTP?

I want to run a javascript applet on a client machine with confidence that the code wasn't modified.  Are there any clever tricks to sign the code or deliver it safely without going the usual route of HTTPS and a certificate?

Comment: Just curious - Why would you not use https?

Comment: You should never rely on javascript for safety. If someone can modify your html, so can ca modify your javascript.

Comment: Just curious if it is possible.

Comment: I, for one, look forward to the days of quantum cryptography, when we return back to this question and say, "Yep, that's possible now."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not really. By the time you make it secure, you'll have had to reinvent at least 90% of HTTPS (or something very similar, anyway) -- but probably have done an inferior job of it. No insult intended, but *very* few people are capable of designing something like this adequately. The usual is for a specialist (or a few of them) to design it as well as they can, and still plan on having to fix at least a few problems over the next few years as more cryptanalysts look at it. Chances of a non-specialist getting it right the first time are right up there with those of winning a major lottery and being hit by lightning at exactly the same moment.

Comment: +1, both for correctness and for the electrifyingly vivid example.

Answer (score 1):

In one form or another, public key cryptography would be involved, I believe.  You could probably implement it yourself, but it would probably be insecure and difficult.  Why do you want to not use HTTPS?  It exists for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If it's javascript, then you can't even confirm that the person on the *client machine* hasn't modified your applet whether you use SSL or not.

Comment: I'm ok with the client modifying the code, it's delivering that initial unmodified package over an unsecure line that has me stumped.  (Or being able to detect that the initial package was modified.)

Comment: @arby: It's simply not feasible, prone to error and generally a waste of time to even consider much less pursue.

Answer (score -1):

If they can modify the javascript, then they can remove any checksumming or similar that you put in. Your best bet is to use a javascript obfuscator / minimizer, as that will just make it hard as all hell to change and still run. Yahoo has a good one I believe, as does Google.

This isn't fool-proof but it's probably going to weed out almost everybody considering tampering with your applet. Head over to maps.google.com and have a look at their javascript. Think about sneakily modifying something about it. Probably not gonna happen.

**EDIT: this might not be so good after all, see links below**

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the links